# I have a trouble during npm loading module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I run this commands:

```
Matias@PC MINGW64 ~/Desktop/test2
$ npm init
[ ... ]
$ npm install
$ npm install neataptic --save
$ npm install chai --save
$ electron .

App threw an error during load
ReferenceError: neataptic is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Matias\Desktop\test2\neat.js:6:36)
[...]
```

The line 6 of the file neat.js is:

```
/* Shorten var names */
var { architect, Network, methods, config } = neataptic;
```

I tried also **require('neataptic')**.

But I have that error. 
Where am I wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I assume from your tags, that you're trying to run this in node.js.

From looking at [the source](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic/blob/master/src/neataptic.js), if the neaptaptic module is properly installed, you should be able to do this:

```
const { architect, Network, methods, config } = require('neataptic');
```

If, for some reason, that doesn't work, then you can debug what's doing on by doing this:

```
const neataptic = require('neataptic');
console.log(neataptic);
```

And, see what exports there are from that module.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following Github issue [link](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic/issues/67)  to get a solution, Thanks